# Ajaxed pagination not working as expected on rails 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

On a rails4 app I have a small script to handle ajaxified pagination. The following code GETs the block of HTML via an `index.js.erb` and *and* is supposed execute as script and bind the `click` event on the freshly loaded pagination links:

```
// pagination.js
$(function() {
  $(".pagination a").on("click", $(".pagination a"), function() {
    $(".pagination").html("Loading...");
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

and then `index.js.erb`:

```
// index.js.erb
$("#books").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("books")) %>");
```

This works fine the first time but once the ajaxed results are in, the `on('click')` event is no longer bound to the new pagination links and a click results to a full-page load. I have to put the same code of `pagination.js` inside `index.js.erb` also to ensure that the click event is bound to pagination links again.

Like so:

```
// index.js.erb
$("#books").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("books")) %>");

$(".pagination a").on("click", $(".pagination a"), function() {
  $(".pagination").html("Loading...");
  $(".loader").removeClass("hidden");
  $.getScript(this.href);
  return false;
});
```

This doesn't seem right because 1. it is not dry and 2. I expected `on('click, function(){ ... });` to *just work*; like the `.live(click, function(){ ... })` method would have with the older version of jQuery.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the click event is not binded to the dynamically created content on your page, it only gets binded to the elements (in your case `.pagination a`) which were present at the time of page load and therefore it only works once.
To do that you have to bind the click event like shown below,

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".pagination a", function(){
  //your code goes here..
});
```

Some more information:

> **Event handlers** are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event handlers.
>
> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time

Comment: You mean to say `.on("click", $(".pagination a"), function() { ... }` should be `.on("click", ".pagination a", function() { ... }` instead?

Comment: No, its `$(document.body)`, its happening because you are not using delegated events.